# Spring boot app on Cloud with external properties file

Tags: spring-boot, properties, external, cloud-foundry

I have a spring boot application which needs to use a property file. This application will be on the cloud. So, the property file will also be on the coud.

I am using cloud foundry to communicate with the cloud and use 'cf push' to push my spring-boot application.

My question : 
 1. Where and how to store a properties file? Can it be stored on the cloud? How? Or does it need to be stored on git and reference it in your application? 
 2. How to use this properties file which is at the external location ?

Answer (score 3):

You cant have file system access in cloud foundry. You have to keep the config file in classpath itself and load the properties from classpath which is also the default behaviour with Spring boot. Spring boot application.properties file (which is inside src/main/resource) goes inside your jar and springs loads it. Hence when you build a embedded jar/war it goes inside classpath and works directly.

The cloud foundry way of handling properties is through VCAP Variables. You can externalize these properties using the deplyoment manifest which is used during the cf push. 
Inside your manifest yml file define properties as below.

```
env:
    myprop1: myvalue1
    myprop2: myvalue2
```

Using this approach all the properties for your app would be available as normal System Properties. You can access them in your application as System.getProperties() inside your Java code.

```
https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-APPLICATION 

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html
```

The major drawback with these two approaches is that the application needs to be rebuilt/repushed to the cloud foundry. The application cant read change in the properties dynamically once application is up and running.

To overcome this Spring-cloud has a project cloud-config. This can be backed by GIT or few other types of Datasource like File System/ Vault etc. This run as a different configuration service. 
You can define the config server inside your application properties file which makes application read properties from the Config service.

```
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html
```

Mostly when u need to centralize the properties in a microservice architecture you can go for config service approach.

Comment: 1. Why doesn't cloud foundry provide file system access?

Comment: 2. I want my spring-boot application to be deployed on cloud once only. However, I want to be able to change my properties file contents later without having the need to redeploy my spring-boot-application on cloud. Can this be achieved using application.properties? Can we reload application .properties only even after deploying spring-boot application?

Comment: Cloud foundry runs in a virtual environment. Each instance of the application runs in its own isolated container. Hence File systems are just temporary. Read this link to understand how cloud foundry works. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem    You cant achieve reload application properties. Once you change some properties then u need to rebuild and cf push the app to cloud foundry. You may have to consider using spring cloud config server for your use case.

Comment: Not really related to the question, but saying "You cant have file system access in cloud foundry." is not correct.  You have full access to a filesystem.  It's not shared in any way though, so each app instance has its own file system and as mentioned in the previous comment, the file system presented to your app is ephemeral, which puts limits on it's usefulness.

Comment: As rightly mentioned by @Daniel Mikusa the file system on cloud foundry is ephermel. If application goes down then application may not be restarted on the same vm instance. CF can choose a different VM available to run the app. Hence file system is just temporary.

Comment: @Tiya no you cannot. spring boot has to read application.properties in jar file for no good reason. I believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

As rightly pointed out, it is best suited to use the Spring-Cloud Config service. The service would have the credentials to hit a Git Repo (url,username and password mostly) and then you can get the properties.

Usually one would define deployment files( manifest files with profiles). So, if you go with a Test environment giving **Dspring.profiles.active = Test**, your application would use this to load up.

The other side of the story is to have multiple profiles defined in CloudConfigService as well. You can switch between those by using **spring.cloud.config.label = youLabel**. Using ConfigService does help since it also provides a easy way to toggle between configs using the profile selection